# How to pass an arbitrary number of parameters while adhering to REST principles

Tags: api, rest, database-design, api-design

I have a database with 3 tables: `product`, `category`, and `xref_product_category`. My business logic permits a product to be associated with an arbitrary number of categories (bed, bath, kitchen, etc.). In terms of designing a REST API, what's the best way to establish these relationships?

For some reason I'm hesitant to pass a JSON array of category IDs as a parameter, but I don't really have a good reason *not* to. I suppose the other option would be to make a series of `PUT` calls, passing a single parameter each time. What's the most RESTful way to establish multiple relationships like this? Should this be done in a single API call, or in multiple calls?

Comment: *For some reason I'm hesitant to pass a JSON array of category IDs as a parameter, but I don't really have a good reason not to.* So do you have a reason or not?

Comment: @ikinciviking: I haven't seen many well-known APIs take an array as a parameter. I realize this isn't a strong reason, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In REST, the phrase "arbitrary number of parameters" usually means "representation".

The parameters as a whole could most likely be combined into payload content to represent a resource.

So firstly define the schema for the payload, and then you'll have a media type that can be used to represent it. Document the schema and tell the people who will use the API that they can POST or PUT with that content to define your product and its arbitrary relationships to other resources.

Then define the URI for your `product` resource and how clients will navigate to it from a Cool (entry-point) URI to it.

Comment: Through what stretch of the imagination is a set of categories a resource?

Comment: I'm saying that if the OP's `product` resource can contain an arbitrary number of links to other resources, then creating/modifying products using POST/PUT should be done by codifying those links (as well as other attributes of the product type) within a payload. In other words, the set of categories it belongs to should be part of the resource, and codified within its representation.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant that the set of categories would _be_ a resource.

Answer (score 0):

I would allow the parameters to be passing in any order.